# CKEditor incompatible with 'limit HTML tags' text filter?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, input-formats

I'm using CKEditor Module 7.x-1.15 with CKEditor v4.4.4. This is applied to the Drupal 'Filtered HTML' text format.

I want to filter out `<DIV>` tags, so have checked 'Limit allowed HTML tags' in the text format settings.

If I enter `<DIV>test</DIV>` into the field, CKEditor converts this to `&lt;div&gt;test&lt;/div&gt;`. So upon save, the filter doesn't recognise the tag and `<DIV>test</DIV>` still displays when viewing the node.

By default, CKEditor is escaping HTML entities.

In the CKEditor profile settings, there is an option to set HTML Entities to No but it seems to make no difference.

I was able to force `config.basicEntities = FALSE;` into the Custom JavaScript Configuration setting. But this seems to generate lots of extraneous `<P>` tags.

Is it better to disable the core text format filter, and try using a CKEditor plugin to strip tags instead?

Comment: `&lt;div&gt;` is not a tag, so everything works exactly as expected, isn't it? Why would you want to forbid your users to write *about* `<div>` tags? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I see your point. But <div> is a tag, and users have a habit of pasting them into text fields along with other 'not allowed' markup. Surely that's the purpose of a having a 'limit allowed HTML tags' filter in core?

Comment: Purpose was to prevent users from breaking your layout with tags, not to prevent them from talking about tags - and talking about tags is all they actually can do now.

Comment: If I disable wysiwyg on the filtered text format, Drupal correctly strips out div tags. When enabled, CKEditor prevents this from happening. That is the issue here.